# PHP: Using $count++ in an if condition

Tags: php, loops, conditional-statements

I'm wondering if the $count++ way of incrementing a counter is okay to use in a conditional statement? Will the variable maintain it's new value?

```
$count = 0;
foreach ($things as $thing){
    if($count++ == 1) continue;
    ...
}
```

Comment: I suppose you've tested it and found results you didn't understand. Can you share the details with us?

Comment: This should work.  `$count++` will increment `$count` and return its *original* value.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

- $count++ is a post-increment. That means that it will increment **after** the evaluation.
- ++$count is a pre-increment. That means that it will increment **before** the evaluation.

http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.operators.increment.php

To answer your question, that is perfectly valid, just keep in check that your value will be 2  *after* the if has been done.

Comment: Just out of curiosity, shouldn't `$count` be 1 after the evaluation. It's `0` to begin with. Incrementing would give you `1` would it not? I may be missing something though.

Comment: @War10ck: No, the if will be true if $count is 1, but since it's a post-increment, AFTER the if is determined to be true, THEN $count will be incremented, so it will be 2.  The first iteration through the loop will evaluate the conditional to be false.

Comment: @GeminiDomino Ahhh, yes. Sorry that was a really dumb question. I see it now. Thanks buddy. Appreciate the explanation. :)

Comment: De nada. Pre/post-incrementation, I've learned, can be deceptively nuanced. :)

Answer (score 2):

Yes, it will, but you want to pay attention to the difference between $count++(post-incrementation) and ++$count(pre-incrementation), or you might not get the results you expect.

For instance, the code snippet you wrote will "continue" on the second "$thing", but go through the loop on the first, because the value of $count won't be incremented until after its value is tested. If that's what you're going for, then right on, but it's one of those common "gotchas", so I thought I should mention it.